# I can not click on this element after finding it using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

[image]

class SeleniumConfig(unittest.TestCase):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.absolute = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/chromedriver.exe"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.absolute, options=options)


def jupiter_4(self):
    self.driver.get('http://jupiter.cloud.planittesting.com')
    self.assertIn("Jupiter Toys", self.driver.title)
    self.driver.find_element_by_id("nav-shop").click()
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "products.ng-scope"))
        )
    except NoSuchElementException as error:
        print(error)
    cow = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[6]/div/p/a[@class='btn btn-success']")
    cows = self.driver.execute_script("add(item);", cow)
    print(cows)
    for each in cow:
        print(each.text)
        print(each)

    time.sleep(10)
    self.driver.quit()
```

when i'm not using the .click() method, it returns a string for it which is
Buy
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7f3a4bb0a1292e42decc229b9769256d", element="0562332e-3d36-46c0-89ba-2601c916a67e")>

however when i try to .click() it returns me a list out of bounds

I'm not sure why it's returning me a list since i've added the exact fullxpath towards the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cow = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[6]/div/p/a[@class='btn btn-success']")
try:
for each in cow:
print(each.text)
print(each.click())
except AttributeError:
pass

It seems that the list has several indexes and can be clicked if i iterate through it.